# Makefile:1: *** missing separator. Stop error when using Make with a config file with no tabs or spaces

Tags: makefile, symlink

I have seen this question and has read its many answers. I understand that this problem usually (always??) appears because of a mistake in using tabs vs spaces in Makefiles. So far that is the general case.

In my case, I have found the error in the title but not when doing make with a Makefile I suspect.

I do:

```
make a_configuration_file
```

and I get

```
Makefile:1: *** missing separator. Stop.
```

I suppose this **"1"** means that the error is occurring in the first line of the file, right?
This `a_configuration_file` is actually a generated file and the first lines are copied here :

```
#
# Automatically generated file; DO NOT EDIT.
# Ambarella SDK Configuration
#
CONFIG_THREADX=y
CONFIG_BOOT_CORE_SRTOS=0
```

So my questions for my particular case are:

1. The "1" refers to the comment line "#"? or the CONFIG_THREADX line?
2. This configuration file is not using Tabs. So what could be the problem?

EDIT:

Robert tells me that the problem could be the end-of-line. I checked with `cat -A a_configuration_file` and it seems there are no \r characters (I ve had problems with this before so I learned how to check for end-of-line chars)

Wander Nauta tells me the problem is in the `Makefile`. Which Makefile should I check? Right now there is a Makefile in the directory from where I call make and it is like this

```
build/Makefile
```

no tabs or spaces
I also did `cat -A Makefile` and I got

```
build/Makefileroot@themachine.....
```

If you are wondering what is that, is just that it seems that the Makefile does not have an end of the line at the end, so the cat command prints the contents and the rest (root@themachine...) is just the normal line in the command line

EDIT2:

I think I am close to finding the error.
Originally the "Makefile" was a link as in

```
ls ./ -l

lrwxrwxrwx 1 1133 543 13 Mar 18  Makefile -> build/Makefile
```

However now it is just a plain text file

```
ls ./ -l

-rw------- 1 11250 10513 14 Jul 6 Makefile
```

Somehow in the linux-windows-linux transference the link condition got lost

Comment: what about end-of-line character for this file? `\r`, `\r\n` or `\r`. Maybe the file is using an incorrect end-of-line character.

Comment: The problem is not in `a_configuration_file`. The problem is in `Makefile`.

Comment: @WanderNauta which file should I look for?

Comment: Yes, the file called `Makefile` in the current directory. Could you check the first few lines of that file for strange characters, and if you don't find any, add those first few lines to the question?

Comment: @WanderNauta How do you do that? I edited the question with some results. (The makefile has only one line)

Comment: Ah. The one-line snippet you posted is apparently _called_ Makefile but it is not a Makefile. That explains the error, but I don't know enough about "Ambarella SDK" to know why it would have a file like that.

Comment: @WanderNauta  when it refers to error in the 1rst line, does that include the comments? or is it the first command?

Comment: It appears that if ask make to run a "makefile" that consists of that line with no end-of-line, Make reports a "missing separator" error. The file `a_configuration_file` has nothing to do with it.

Answer (score 0):

> In my case, I have found the error in the title but not when doing make with a Makefile I suspect.

The error in the title specifies the name of the file in which the error is encountered: `Makefile`.  Thus, your suspicion about "not when doing so with a Makefile" is unfounded.  Although it is possible to run `make` without a makefile, and doing so can even be advantageous, `make` will always read a makefile if it can find one by one of the default names it looks for.

Moreover, though it may not be obvious in this case, the name given in the message is not just a base name but a (relative) path to the file.  It is therefore complaining about a file named `Makefile` in `make`'s working directory.

> Right now there is a Makefile in the directory from where I call make
> and it is like this
>
> ```
> build/Makefile
> ```
>
> no tabs or spaces I also did cat -A Makefile and I got
>
> ```
> build/Makefileroot@themachine.....
> ```

Those two claims do not appear to be consistent with each other.  In any case, however, neither one attributes valid makefile content to the makefile in question.  This is likely the cause of the error message, which would then be a bit misleading.

It looks like you may be trying to have one makefile specify that another make be run in the `build/` directory -- a so-called "recursive make".  There are a couple of variations on how that is done, and they differ slightly in effect, but here's a guess at what you might be after for that top-level `Makefile`:

```
all:
        $(MAKE) -C build
```

Of course, that second line needs to be indented with a leading tab, not spaces.

That will cause the top-level `make` run to trigger a second `make` run with the `build/` directory as the second's working directory.

Comment: Thanks!. I am having a suspicion, please hear me out. This project (that I do not control) has been going linux-windows-linux and so for. Isn't it possible that this "Makefile" is actually a dynamic link to the other makefile (the one in build directory) and that when transfered to windows became a text file. I kind of remember seeing something like this some years ago... could that be possible?

Comment: My memory is shady about this, it might be symbolic links and actually working on windows but not linux

Comment: @KansaiRobot, the scenario you describe is plausible.  If that indeed is how the problem arose, then converting `Makefile` back into a symbolic link to `build/Makefile` or copying the contents of `build/Makefile` to `Makefile` might resolve the issue.  However, you would need to be concerned that other symbolic links on which the build relies might also have been corrupted.

Comment: Another possible correction for a corrupted symlink problem with the top-level `Makefile`, which would be resistant to fresh corruption without introducing code duplication, would be to use a different recursive `make` variation, where the command executed by the top-level `Makefile` is instead `$(MAKE) -f build/Makefile`.  That will run `make` in the *current* working directory, using the `build/Makefile` as the makefile.